# MongoDB performing slow read-queries under load

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm running a MongoDB on my VPS. Two instances of the same python bot are constantly reading and writing documents. Essentially, they continously repeat the following steps infinitely:

1. Get a document using `find_and_modify()` (no i cannot use `find()` here)
2. process data fetched in step 1 (takes 10-60 seconds)
3. update document using `find_and_modify()` (no i cannot use `update()` here)

This worked flawlessly until I deployed a REST API web server to view the results in the browser etc. Now whenever the bot instances and the web server are running at the same time, the bots slow down by minutes and a request to my web server takes 2 minutes. When either the bots or the web server are/is running, they both query the database within milliseconds.

Before I think about upgrading my VPS' RAM and CPU, I would like to understand what exactly causes this. I assume the problem lies in the database being overwhelmed with the amount of requests from the 3 clients (2 bot instances, 1 web server).

I found the command `currentOp()`, but I'm having issues understanding its return.

```
> db.currentOp({"secs_running": {"$gte": 5}})
{
        "inprog" : [
                {
                        "type" : "op",
                        "host" : "localhost:27017",
                        "desc" : "conn1555",
                        "connectionId" : 1555,
                        "client" : "127.0.0.1:37750",
                        "clientMetadata" : {
                                "driver" : {
                                        "name" : "PyMongo",
                                        "version" : "3.11.3"
                                },
                                "os" : {
                                        "type" : "Linux",
                                        "name" : "Linux",
                                        "architecture" : "x86_64",
                                        "version" : "5.4.0-71-generic"
                                },
                                "platform" : "CPython 3.8.5.final.0"
                        },
                        "active" : true,
                        "currentOpTime" : "2021-04-27T13:37:56.261+00:00",
                        "opid" : 3151480,
                        "lsid" : {
                                "id" : UUID("71d36512-c5a3-4fe9-b3f9-31fd23e86413"),
                                "uid" : BinData(0,"47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=")
                        },
                        "secs_running" : NumberLong(123),
                        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(123430156),
                        "op" : "command",
                        "ns" : "nxmain.websites",
                        "command" : {
                                "aggregate" : "websites",
                                "pipeline" : [
                                        {
                                                "$match" : {

                                                }
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "$group" : {
                                                        "_id" : 1,
                                                        "n" : {
                                                                "$sum" : 1
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                ],
                                "cursor" : {

                                },
                                "lsid" : {
                                        "id" : UUID("71d36512-c5a3-4fe9-b3f9-31fd23e86413")
                                },
                                "$db" : "nxmain",
                                "$readPreference" : {
                                        "mode" : "primaryPreferred"
                                }
                        },
                        "planSummary" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "numYields" : 934,
                        "locks" : {
                                "ReplicationStateTransition" : "w",
                                "Global" : "r",
                                "Database" : "r",
                                "Collection" : "r"
                        },
                        "waitingForLock" : false,
                        "lockStats" : {
                                "ReplicationStateTransition" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "w" : NumberLong(936)
                                        }
                                },
                                "Global" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "r" : NumberLong(936)
                                        }
                                },
                                "Database" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "r" : NumberLong(936)
                                        }
                                },
                                "Collection" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "r" : NumberLong(936)
                                        }
                                },
                                "Mutex" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "r" : NumberLong(2)
                                        }
                                }
                        },
                        "waitingForFlowControl" : false,
                        "flowControlStats" : {

                        }
                },
                {
                        "type" : "op",
                        "host" : "localhost:27017",
                        "desc" : "conn1535",
                        "connectionId" : 1535,
                        "client" : "127.0.0.1:36886",
                        "clientMetadata" : {
                                "driver" : {
                                        "name" : "PyMongo",
                                        "version" : "3.11.3"
                                },
                                "os" : {
                                        "type" : "Linux",
                                        "name" : "Linux",
                                        "architecture" : "x86_64",
                                        "version" : "5.4.0-71-generic"
                                },
                                "platform" : "CPython 3.8.5.final.0"
                        },
                        "active" : true,
                        "currentOpTime" : "2021-04-27T13:37:56.261+00:00",
                        "opid" : 3152992,
                        "secs_running" : NumberLong(7),
                        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(7503765),
                        "op" : "command",
                        "ns" : "admin.$cmd",
                        "command" : {
                                "ismaster" : 1,
                                "topologyVersion" : {
                                        "processId" : ObjectId("60845741af792cc59a636f20"),
                                        "counter" : NumberLong(0)
                                },
                                "maxAwaitTimeMS" : 10000,
                                "$db" : "admin",
                                "$readPreference" : {
                                        "mode" : "primary"
                                }
                        },
                        "numYields" : 0,
                        "waitingForLatch" : {
                                "timestamp" : ISODate("2021-04-27T13:37:48.858Z"),
                                "captureName" : "AnonymousLatch"
                        },
                        "locks" : {

                        },
                        "waitingForLock" : false,
                        "lockStats" : {

                        },
                        "waitingForFlowControl" : false,
                        "flowControlStats" : {

                        }
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

As you can see there are two operations in the pipeline. The one with `secs_running: 123` is the web server, the other one is one of the bot instances, which takes about 10-20 seconds when the web server is running in parallel.

What could be the cause for my problem and how can I solve it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: One of the operations is an admin command. Is it the webserver or the bots?

Comment: What is the purpose of that aggregation pipeline?

Comment: Slow queries (updates. reads, deletes) can be analyzed to figure the reason - generate a _query plan_.

Comment: @Sergio: The admin command is that of the REST API's web server. @Joe Good point! investigated a little more. The aggregation pipeline is what mongodb does when using the pymongo command ```collection.count_documents({})``` to count all documents in my collection. For some reason when the filter is ```{}``` that takes forever (specifying ```{"_id": {"$exists": true}}``` doesn't speed it up, but using the deprecated command ```collection.count()``` does). But still not quite fast.